# Autocomplete pop up menu

Tags: css, html, reactjs, responsive-design

For mobiles devices I have menu fixed at the bottom of screen. `position: fixed;`

In this div is `input` with autocomplete. On desktop this is dropdown

```
<div style="postition:fixed; bottom:0;">
<div style="position:relative;">
<input type="text">
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;">
autocomplete list
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd like show this autocomplete above input. Of course it works with `bottom:100%`

But when I have opened virtual keyboard and use it all time it "skip" under keyboard and on correct position.

Any hints how to set autocomplete list for block fixed at the bottom of mobile screen.

Possible is important that this component is rendering by reactJS.

Correct position is https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/2I2v1B3d0k3i2O0o122F/%5B7f0b55f5b92f3d66db3ce4d2f544fa2f%5D_Image%25202017-10-27%2520at%25202.54.03%2520PM.png?v=595301e1 when I enter any letter it skip under virtual keyboard.

Thanks in advance for any hints.